# 2 Different LD errors when trying to link static library

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, static-libraries, static-linking

I wrote a custom C++ library, which compiled correctly, and am trying to write a test program for some different accuracy checks.

When I compile it this way:

```
$ c++ -I./include/ -L./lib -lname test.cpp -c -o test.o
....[succeeds ]
$ c++ -I./include/ -L./lib -lname test.o -o test
```

I get:
`ld: 1 duplicate symbol for...` for the function I'm testing

But when I compile the `test.o` the same way & change the executable method:

`c++ -I./include -L./lib test.o -o test`

it returns: `ld: symbols() not found for ..." for the function I'm testing.

I am 100% sure about the way I compiled & built the library,  so I don't understand exactly what I am doing wrong even after I've tried several different ways of compiling `test`.

Edits:

1. Fixed typo in test filename.
2. Removed `-L` & `-l` flags from step 1, and it compiled.
3. Removed `-I` from step 2, and it gave the error `ld: library for -lname not found` when compiled as:
   `c++ -L./lib -lname test.obj -o test`

Comment: For compiling a .c file better to use a C compiler.

Comment: You certainly don't need the `-lname` and `-L./lib` options in the first step. Whether this does any harm I'm not sure.

Comment: You also don't need the `-I./include` option for the second step.

Comment: the .c is a mistake.

Comment: What if you keep `-I` in the step 2?

Comment: `duplicate symbol...` means that symbol is actually duplicated and you need to fix it

Comment: The first step would be to note *which* symbol is duplicated. Then you can figure out why.

Comment: Order of `-l` options matters to the linker.  You should always put the `-l` options at the END of the link line after all the `.o` files.  `c++ -L./lib -o test test.o -lname`.

Comment: The duplicated symbol is the library function I'm trying to test. Putting -lname at the end still gives the duplicate error.